# Can we edit CMSNavigationNode from Component Editor in SmartEdit?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

SAP Commerce 1811

As per documentation, In SmartEdit, we can add, update, remove parent child navigation node via Navigation Management Tab only.

When we go to site, and start using the navigation node, we can only select it from tree structure.

For example, Account Navigation Component

[image]

In this component, We can only select the navigation node, there is no way we can add, update navigation node from here.

Is there any way to do so or there is only Navigation Management option available where we can manage all the things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the user has access to create items under the content catalog. You could try assigning cmsmanager usergroup to the user, and making sure cmsmanger has write access to the content catalog.

Also, SmartEdit is somewhat buggy. So, try to refresh the page after you make the changes.

See Assigning Users and Usergroups to Content Catalogs: https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/1905/en-US/d94aa34f24fe4613b0f0f2590f544ba7.html

xxx

UPDATE 7/10 21:18 UTC+8: In Hybris 1905.13, SmartEdit has an option to add a child or a sibling node.

[image]

Comment: I am using admin, and my admin has content catalog access. I can able to create links via navigation management link. Just wanted to check if we can edit navigation node (CMSNavigationNode) from component editor. for example in Account Navigation Component, if we click on Replace, we can only select existing navigation node, not able to create/update from here

Comment: @Free-Minded I'm using 1905 right now, and I can see 3 dots on each row. It lets me Add Child, Add Sibling, etc. However, I don't see those dots in the 1811 documentation; I also didn't see it in the 1905 documentation.

Comment: If its working on higher version, can you please update your answer accordingly so that i can accept.

Comment: @Free-Minded Updated with a screenshot. :)